Why a minimum phase system has to have positive pm and gm to be stable?
I'm very familiar with control theory and I came across this statement "minimum phase system has to have positive pm and gm to be stable" from many places. So I have this open-loop transfer function:
$$G=\frac {(s+10)(s+1+2j)(s+1-2j)} {(s+2)(s+4+10j)(s+4-10j)}$$
This is clearly minimum phase, all poles and zeros are LHP.
The Nyquist plot or bode plot actually shows it has NEGATIVE phase margin -99.2 degree. But it turns out the closed loop transfer function G/(1+G) is stable.
Am I doing anything wrong, or the statement self is actually wrong?
Update:
So i read this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9199357 and think the phase margin should never exceed 180 deg nor below -180 deg. This is telling me the -99.2 degree from MATLAB makes sense. I believe the statement "minimum phase system can only be stable if pm and gm are both positive" is wrong in this sense.

@ Frank Ma - May I ask you: Wat is the physical meaning of the pure imginary variables in your function?

Hi LvW,  what do you mean by pure imginary variables?  The j?  It can be replaced by "i" though.  The zeros and poles are not on imaginary axis in this function.  I just made up this expression.

Example: Simple 1st oder lowpass: H(s)=1/(1+sT)=(1/T)/[s + (1/T)]. Evaluation: The transfer contains the complex frequency variable "s" and a constant value (dimension 1/time). This applies to all similar transfer functions. How comes an expression like "aj" into the function? Which dimension?

I simply mean there are one real zero s=-10, and two conjugate zero s = -1+2j, s=-1-2j in the nominator, and one pole s=-2, two conjugate pole s= -4+10j, s=-4-10j.

Theoretical function. My simulation shows ~ 260 ° phase margin ... How did you obtain ~ -99 ° ?

in MATLAB G= (s+10)(s+1+2j)(s+1-2j)/((s+2)(s+4+10j)(s+4-10j)); margin(G); nyquist(G);

It turns out the matlab interpret the phase margin as negative value. In nyquist, the crossing over unit circle happens in first quadrant.

@ Frank Ma - the phase of the loop gain function crosses the zero-deg line twice. As a consequence, the concept of stability margin (GM, PM in the Bode diagram) must not be applied to the given system. For stability analysis, the Nyqist plot must be used.

Made with microcap v12
Here is what I found with simulation. Closed loop in green, open loop in blue.

Stability simulation, does show only phase margin = ~ 260 °.

Nyquist figure. Shows phase margin and gain margin.


The interesting thing is, MATLAB is reporting -99.2 degree based on the 180 degree line in phase plot rather than -180 degree line. In Nyquist plot, it also reports the same results which interprets the crossing of unti circle in first qudrant by a negative phase margin.

@ Frank Ma - as I have written in my other comment, the concept of phase margin does not apply to your function (two phase crossings)

@LvW from nyquist plot and bode plot, it only has one gain crossing and no phase crossing, which implies there is a PM defined and infinite large GM.

@ Frank Ma - No, you are wrong. Have a detailed look at the first part (low frequencies) of the Nyquist plot
